# Communications between two computers possible without authentication

Tags: networking, ethernet, data-transfer, ata

Situation: To establish communications between two computers, and get ATA over Ethernet/iSCSI/any similar protocols to work so as to connect the storage as a network attachment storage.

Problem: I do not have access to the target (I have the initiator) -- the most I can do is to plug an ethernet cable into it.

Question: Is it possible to communicate between two computers by just plugging in the ethernet cable (I can do initiator side programming to help establish the connection, but can it communicate?)

Additional information 1: Initiator is a Linux OS, target is a Windows OS

Additional information 2: I thought of using SATA but I do not have access to the internals of the computer

Additional information 3: USB-to-USB and Wireless Network NAS is too slow for me to be able to use.

Additional information 4: Initiator program is written in Python

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have access to the target you can't do this in the general case.  Its common sense - its a major security risk, no one in their right mind would allow it.

About the best you could (maybe) do is use Ethernet Booting to boot a customised OS to do what you want.  This means you only need to plug in an ethernet cable on the target end..... IF THE TARGET END PREFERS Ethernet booting over regular booting - which would strike me as an uncommon setup.